# Windows 7 tries to run my USB drive instead of exploring it

Tags: windows-7, usb, windows-explorer

When I double-click my USB drive, which I just formated to NTFS, windows tries to run it as if there was an application in it. However, the drive is empty. I can still right-click the drive in My Computer and explore it, but I'm curious as to why the double-click does this.

When i right-click the drive, the top option in the list, in bold, says "Run or install program from your media".

Any ideas ?

Comment: in the right click options , was there also a "open" in there somewhere?  You do realise without scaring you, the pattern for a virus trying to spread using that method would be tossing a autorun in, some would attempt to get that data on the drive as soon as it is plugged in.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you've got hidden `autorun.inf` file in the root of your USB drive. You shouldn't have this file after formatting a drive (Unless this is U3 Flash drive and the autorun file is located on different partition).

Double click to open a specified file (like a .exe program or text file) is actually one of Windows autorun feature.

Worth to be noted, putting `autorun.inf` (and its .exe file) on abitrary inserted drive is a known replicating behavior of Autorun malware  (See Wikipedia on [Autorun](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AutoRun)).

--

I'd try making Windows Explorer to show all hidden files including "protected OS file", followed by deleting any of hidden autorun files I found.

### Here's how

On any Explorer window click `Organize` then `File and Folder Options`, then switch to `View` tab

Make sure the the highlighted ones are set this way:

[image: Folder Options, show hidden files]

Finally see whether there are any file on the root of your USB drives. If any, delete `autorun.inf` and any unknown file you found. Since you said you just formatted your drive I'd assume it's safe to delete everything else.

**Try to replug your drive.**

(You can undo the changes in folder and options setting).